# I cannot close JFrame

Tags: java, swing, dispose

I have two java forms: NewJFrame i NewJFrame1. I have button on NewJFrame, so when I click on that button to open NewJFrame1 and close NewJFrame. It can open NewJFrame1, but it cannot close NewJFrame. 
This:
    NewJFrame frame = new NewJframe();
    frame.setVisible(false);
doesn't work. Also, frame.dispose(); doesnt work. CAn someone help me to soleve problem, how can I close NewJFrame by clicking on button in it (NewJFrame).

Comment: Please provide a simple piece of code which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The way you are describing it should work. Please post your code.

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861139/how-to-go-back-to-the-previous-gui-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-java/30861643#30861643

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
```

creates a new (second) instance of NewJFrame. If you want to close the original one, you need a reference to this instance. Depending on your code, the reference could be `this`, so

```
this.dispose();
```

could work.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please indicate so by marking my answer as accepted (and/or upvoting it).

Answer (score 1):

Check if is frame visible before u trying to close it...Maybe u are trying to close wrong instance of frame... if u have  NewJFrame frame = new NewJframe()
then this same frame need to be closed .

frame.setVisible(false);
or 
frame.dispose();

Just do dispose on original instance do not do `JFrame frame = new JFrame()`twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. Hope, it will work.

```
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand why you are doing this, but I provided you a working sample :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Tester implements ActionListener {
    private static final String SHOW = "show";
    private final JButton displayer = new JButton(SHOW);
    private final JButton hider = new JButton("hide");
    private final JFrame f;
    private final JFrame f1;

    Tester(){
        displayer.addActionListener(this);
        hider.addActionListener(this);

        f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.add(displayer);
        f.add(hider);
        f.setVisible(true);

        f1 = new JFrame();
        f1.setSize(500, 500);
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f1.add(new JLabel("empty frame"));  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tester();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            f1.setVisible(arg0.getActionCommand().equals(SHOW));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your help... I am working all with DragAndDrop so I am not sure how to use these listeners..